# Toggle Column visibility using class in dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I know that to toggle the visibility in a column using the [dataTables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) I only have to do:

```
function fnShowHide( iCol ){
    /* Get the DataTables object again - this is not a recreation, just a get of the object */
    var oTable = $('#content-table-redesign').dataTable();

    var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
    oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
}
```

but is it possible to get the column using an ID or Class or another mean?

The thing is I am also allowing the user to drag and drop the columns to will and if I go by index then they may be clicking to hide "id" (column 0) but they moved it somewhere else and now whatever is in the position 0 gets hidden instead of the "id" one.

Either that, or somehow trick the plugin to still link the column index regardless of where it's moved to.

**EDIT**

Here's the HTML the body is basically the same (each td has the same class as its th parent)

```
 <table id="content-table-redesign" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ID">ID</th>
                    <th class="Name">Name</th>
                    <th class="Domain">Domain</th>
                    <th class="email">email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

I'm looking for the class, because the one that contains that class is the one that will be removed thead and tbody alike

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest answer is simply that dataTables doesn't support this natively and that you'll need to manually pull the index based on class yourself.  Luckily, this is easy!

```
var iCol = $('#content-table-redesign tr').first().children('td.yourclass').index();
var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
```

Your selector may need to use `th.yourclass` depending on your table structure, of course.  So it might read instead:

```
$('#content-table-redesign thead tr').children('th.yourclass').index();
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your HTML, here's your selector:

```
$('#content-table-redesign thead tr').children('th.ID').index();
```

You'll note the console logs "0":  http://jsfiddle.net/YeAHB/

Comment: I always get an index of -1 any idea why? No matter if it's visible or not or if it has or not been rearranged

Comment: You'll have to post your HTML and what you're searching for.

Comment: Adam's right, but watch out. The moment you filter or sort you've got the whole order mixed up.

Comment: And I've updated my answer.  Works fine for me in the Fiddle.

Comment: Incognito, how would sorting or filtering adjust the position of the columns?  Your comment here and your answer below makes me think you're confusing this with table rows....

Comment: Adam, yeah, I actually did confuse this with rows. Deleted. Oops :P.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of DataTables you can specify the class name and show/hide the columns.

```
var data_table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
data_table.columns('.location-col').visible(true);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this plugin, but depending on the html structure, you can use jQuery .index() to find what is the index of the child...

Take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UwQ35/

Comment: This would require every row to have an ID. That's not efficient, especially when the DOM already gives you a structure to work with.

Comment: The ID is just an example, could be a class (which is what he wanted)